# Why are DNS changes required for SSL?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ip, ssl-certificate

I don't really understand how this works. When installing an SSL, does your site get a different IP or why is the DNS change required?

Comment: What DNS changes have you been told are required?

Comment: Like SpacemanSpiff said, there shouldn't be any changes to dns required.  Can you expand on what dns change you think is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any DNS changes "required" but the FQDN on the SSL certificate must match the URL looked up to resolve the website, or the certificate may need a wildcard at the front to server multiple potential hosts with a single cert. I've never had to make any "changes" to my records for SSL, but I did have to make sure that things matched.

Comment: The DNS changes eluded to are most probably because of the DV type of certificates where the CA will ask a specific `TXT` record to be inserted in the domain zone to prove ownership.